# Connection timing out?

Tags: ruby, net-sftp

I have simple connection object

```
require 'net/sftp'
@con = Net::SFTP.start(@@host, @@username, :password => @@password
...
@con.upload!(filepath, destination)
```

I have this in a script that listens for files being dropped into a folder. The files are collected, and uploaded to a remote sfpt server. It all works fine, but it seems after the script is left running for long enough, it will break and throw this error:

```
exception while processing events: Write to the server failed
```

I can only assume this happens because the idle connection is disconnecting after a certain amount of time.
Is there away to keep the connection open indefinitely? or is that a limitation?

If thats not possible, is there away I can manage the error? Something like:

```
begin
    @con.upload!(filepath, destination)
rescue Net::SFTPStatusException => e
    if e.code == 7 //connection lost code
        @con.{reconnect}//Whatever this would look like
    end
    else
        raise
    end
end
```

Not sure if 7 is the right error code, or how I could reconnect the connection object.

Comment: Are you not starting a new connection each time you try and upload?

Comment: No, there can be many uploads in succession, so I don't want to create a new connection each time something comes up. Handling the dropped connection makes more sense to me.

Answer (score 1):

Since this uses SFTP, i.e. it is proxied over SSH, it may be possible to send a 'ping' every X seconds to keep the connection open. You can do this with `ServerAliveInterval` in `~/.ssh/config` or `/etc/ssh/sshd_config`, for example:

```
Host *
  ServerAliveInterval 240
```

Also note that any options passed to `Net::SFTP.start` are passed to the `Net::SSH.start` so you can use [options](https://net-ssh.github.io/ssh/v1/chapter-2.html) such as `verbose: :debug` to get more information about what is happening.

Another option would be to do something like list files in some directory within the loop which waits for a file to be uploaded in order to keep the connection active. It might also be possible to do this in a separate thread if SSH connections to the same host are shared.

Answer (score 0):

ruby net/sftp has it's own parameter of the connection keepalive

- **keepalive**: set to +true+ to send a keepalive packet to the SSH server when there's no traffic between the SSH server and Net::SSH client for the keepalive_interval seconds. Defaults to +false+.
- **keepalive_interval**: the interval seconds for keepalive. Defaults to +300+ seconds.
- **keepalive_maxcount**: the maximun number of keepalive packet miss allowed. Defaults to 3

## Example-Code

```
require 'net/ssh'
require 'net/sftp'
require 'net/sftp/constants'
require 'logger'

$SFTP_REMOTE_IP = '1.1.1.1'
$SFTP_REMOTE_USER = 'keepmealive'

sshlog = Logger.new(STDOUT)
sshlog.formatter = proc do |severity, datetime, progname, msg|
   "[RUBY SFTP-CLIENT] #{msg}\n"
end
sshlog.level = Logger::ERROR

sftp = Net::SFTP.start($SFTP_REMOTE_IP, $SFTP_REMOTE_USER, port: 22, timeout: 15, keepalive: true, keepalive_interval: 5, keepalive_maxcount: 2, logger: sshlog, verbose: 1)

# Wait to see keepalive
sleep 20

sftp.channel.eof! unless sftp.channel.nil? # Close SFTP channel
sftp.close_channel() unless sftp.nil? # Close SFTP
```

## Log Output

```
[RUBY SFTP-CLIENT] sending lstat packet (10)
[RUBY SFTP-CLIENT] channel_data: 0 41b
[RUBY SFTP-CLIENT] sending keepalive 0
[RUBY SFTP-CLIENT] sending global request keepalive@openssh.com
```